How to delete a drawn feature using the draw.delete in mapbox?
I am able to create but not delete drawn features on the map.
I am able to draw features, and in the console I can see the feature ID, however when I click on the delete button, the features are not being deleted. It says in the console that they are, and that it does not find any other features (an empty array is returned). Maybe the drawn feature is being stored locally and in the LocalStorage as well. One of them gets deleted and the other still shows. Would appreciate any help. Here's the code:
DrawControl.jsx
import MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';
import '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { BiCircle } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { PiPolygon } from 'react-icons/pi';
import Select, { components as SelectComponents } from 'react-select';
import wellknown from 'wellknown';
import { arraysEqual } from '../../../../helpers/helpers';
import CircleMode from './Circle.DrawControl';
import { DrawControlWrapper, customSelectStyles } from './DrawControl.style';

// Available modes without reset/delete option
const ALL_MODES = \[
{ value: 'polygon', label: 'Polygon', mode: 'draw_polygon', icon: \<PiPolygon size={18} /\> },
{ value: 'circle', label: 'Circle', mode: 'draw_circle', icon: \<BiCircle size={18} /\> }
\];

function DrawControl({ map, controls = \[\], setDrawnFeatures, setIsDrawToolsActive }) {
const \[selectedControl, selectControl\] = useState(null);
const \[availableControls, setAvailableControls\] = useState(\[\]);
const drawRef = useRef(null);
const \[drawnFeatures, setDrawnFeaturesState\] = useState(\[\]); // State to keep track of drawn features
const \[messageShown, setMessageShown\] = useState(false); // State to track message visibility

const updateGeometry = useCallback(
(event) =\> {
if (drawRef.current) {
const feature = event.features\[0\];
const wktGeom = wellknown.stringify(feature.geometry);
console.log("FEATURE",feature)
// Add the new feature to state and the map
setDrawnFeaturesState((prevFeatures) =\> {
const newFeatures = \[...prevFeatures, feature\];
setDrawnFeatures(wktGeom); // Update drawn feature state
return newFeatures;
});

        selectControl(null); // Deselect tool after drawing
      }
    },
    [setDrawnFeatures]

);

const onSelectControl = (option) =\> {
if (!option) {
setIsDrawToolsActive(false);
selectControl(null);
return;
}

    setIsDrawToolsActive(true);
    selectControl(option.value);
    
    if (drawRef.current) {
      drawRef.current.changeMode(option.mode); // Change drawing mode
    }

};

const deleteDrawnFeatures = () =\> {
if (drawRef.current) {
console.log('Delete button clicked');

      // Delete all features from the Mapbox Draw instance
      drawRef.current.deleteAll();
      
      // Verify if the Draw instance is empty
      const remainingFeatures = drawRef.current.getAll().features;
      console.log('Remaining Features after delete:', remainingFeatures);
    
      // Clear the drawn features state
      setDrawnFeaturesState([]);
      setDrawnFeatures(null); // Reset parent state if needed
    
      // Optional: Force re-render by adding/removing a dummy layer
      map.once('idle', () => {
        map.triggerRepaint(); // Refresh map render
      });
    
      console.log('All features deleted');
    } else {
      console.log('No features to delete');
    }

};

useEffect(() =\> {
if (!map) return;

    // Initialize Mapbox Draw instance
    drawRef.current = new MapboxDraw({
      displayControlsDefault: false,
      userProperties: true,
      modes: {
        ...MapboxDraw.modes,
        draw_circle: CircleMode // Add custom circle mode
      }
    });
    
    map.addControl(drawRef.current);
    
    map.on('draw.create', updateGeometry);
    map.on('draw.update', updateGeometry);
    
    return () => {
      map.off('draw.create', updateGeometry);
      map.off('draw.update', updateGeometry);
    };

}, \[map, updateGeometry\]);
useEffect(() =\> {
const syncFeatures = () =\> {
const allFeatures = drawRef.current.getAll().features;
console.log("All Features from Mapbox Draw:", allFeatures); // Check features
setDrawnFeaturesState(allFeatures); // Sync state with Mapbox Draw features
};

    map.on('draw.create', syncFeatures);
    map.on('draw.update', syncFeatures);
    
    return () => {
      map.off('draw.create', syncFeatures);
      map.off('draw.update', syncFeatures);
    };

}, \[map\]);

useEffect(() =\> {
let newControls = \[...controls\];
if (!arraysEqual(newControls, availableControls)) {
setAvailableControls(newControls); // Update available controls
}
}, \[availableControls, controls\]);

// Show message about overwriting only once
useEffect(() =\> {
if (!messageShown) {
setMessageShown(true); // Set message shown to true
}
}, \[messageShown\]);

const IconOption = (props) =\> (
\<SelectComponents.Option {...props}\>
\<span\>{props.data.label}\</span\>
{props.data.icon}
\</SelectComponents.Option\>
);

const availableControlOptions = ALL_MODES.filter((m) =\>
availableControls.includes(m.value)
);

const selectedOption =
availableControlOptions.find((m) =\> m.value === selectedControl) || null;

return (
\<DrawControlWrapper style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', position: 'relative' }}\>
{/\* Render message if not already shown */}
{!messageShown && (
\<div className="notification"\>
Drawing a new feature will overwrite the existing one.
\</div\>
)}
\<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}\>
\<Select
placeholder="Draw"
isClearable
value={selectedOption}
onChange={onSelectControl}
options={availableControlOptions}
components={{ Option: IconOption }}
styles={customSelectStyles}
/\>
{/* Button to delete drawn features \*/}
\<button
onClick={deleteDrawnFeatures}
// disabled={drawnFeatures.length === 0}
style={{
// cursor: drawnFeatures.length === 0 ? 'pointer' : 'pointer',
opacity: drawnFeatures.length === 0 ? 0.5 : 1,
marginLeft: '10px',
padding: '8px 12px',
backgroundColor: '#ff0000', // Red background for emphasis
color: '#fff',
border: 'none',
borderRadius: '4px',
zIndex: 10,
position: 'relative' // Position relative to ensure it stays on top
}}
\\\>
Delete Drawn Features
\</button\>
\</div\>
\</DrawControlWrapper\>
);
}

export default DrawControl;


Update:
I changed the code slightly, now when I Draw the feature, i can see the drawn features when i check the console. Upon deletion attempt, the features dont show in the console anymore but on the map i can see it, along with the points within the boundary of the feature. I feel the map is for some reason not being refreshed probably because of the points, and the feature is not being allowed to be deleted. I tried deletion of the drawn feature (in a case where there were no points within its boundary), and the feature got deleted instantly.
